# phantom-html-to-pdf download pdf to client

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I am using the phantom-html-to-pdf library in an express Node server and I am able to generate the PDF, however it just displays as a load of jibberish on the page.

When saving this page as `.pdf` it is the web page I am trying to encode, so everything is working well except pushing the file to the client as a download.

My code is:

```
router.get('/generatePdf', function(req, res, next) {
    // handle the form that is submitted to this page.
    var conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")();
    conversion({
        numberOfWorkers: 2,
        tmpDir: "os/tmpdir",
        phantomPath: require("phantomjs-prebuilt").path,
        url: "https://google.com"
    }, function(err, pdf) {
        console.log(pdf.logs);
        console.log(pdf.numberOfPages);

        pdf.stream.pipe(res) // this is the issue! 

    });
})
```

I believe I am doing something wrong with the `pdf.stream.pipe(res)` function if I'm honest I don't truly understand this function.

Comment: You probably need to set the `Content-Type` header so that the client knows it's getting a PDF file.

Comment: `res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');`
  `pdf.stream.pipe(res)` works :)
Do you know how to make it open in a new Tab?